# How to override layout file, which is already override by other theme - layout\override\base\somel_ayout.xml

Tags: magento2, layout, overrides

How to override layout file, which is already override by other theme.

For example, we have existing theme.

```
app\design\frontend\<Vendor>\<themeone>\Module_Vendor\layout\override\base\somel_ayout.xml
```

How to override somel_ayout.xml file in my current theme.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does your theme inherit from the other theme? Either way, you should be able to follow the same pattern as the first theme. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-override.html

Comment: Yes, it is not working even my current theme parent theme is <Vendor>\<themeone>, and i have already referred official Magento 2 documentation.

Comment: it won't override but extend other theme xml file

Comment: @klict Can you tell me how to extend.

Comment: can you precise what do you aim by saying override ? is it replacing totally the layout or adding some customisation ?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to override a layout file, create the same folder structure in the theme as in module's `view/frontend`. if the layout is placed in:

`Vendor_ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/some_layout.xml`

then place the file with which you want to override in:

`app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Theme_Name]/Vendor_ModuleName/layout/some_layout.xml`

If your xml is not created properly or contains any error. In this case it will follow the fallback technique.

Comment: above technique will work only when the layout exists in any module. If it does, and then overridden in **themeone** ,  you can override it in your **themetwo** by using the same.

Comment: Please read the question, i want to override a layout file already overrided by  theme override/base. Is there any technique  to achieve this by new theme ? if yes, Please provide the example.

Comment: can you post the snap of the directory structure of this particular theme. I will try to provide the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your `etc/module.xml` file to define your priority file (module/theme):

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Vendor_Test" />
            <module name="Magento_Customer" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```