# How the Base folder will help on Magento 2 modules or themes fallback mechanism

Tags: magento2, overrides, theme-fallback

As from official docs :

> base : used for both front end and admin html.

1. As the part of Magento Theming, how and when to use `base` folder and how the fallback work with `base` folder.
2. As i observed in the modules, we are using base, for example `\vendor\magento\module-wishlist\view\base\layout\catalog_product_prices.xml`
3. As of my knowledge both( Module & theme level) are for overriding, but how Magento 2 will handle the fallback logic for final rendering or merging the changes.

Knowledge sharing will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Source](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/debug-theme.html)**

**base folder** it's default fallbacks for all area and used to share resources across of areas

**Fallback sequence**

1. `<current_theme_dir>/<Namespace>_<Module>/layout/`
2. `<parent_theme(s)_dir>/<Namespace>_<Module>/layout/`
3. `<module_dir>/view/frontend or adminhtml/layout/`
4. `<module_dir>/view/base/layout/`

**[Magento layout processing](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-overview.html#layout_processing)**

1. Collects all layout files from modules. The order is determined by the modules order in the module list from app/etc/config.php.
2. Determines the sequence of inherited themes `[<parent_theme>, ..., <parent1_theme>] <current_theme>`
3. Iterates the sequence of themes from last ancestor to current:

   a. Adds all extending theme layout files to the list.

   b. Replaces overridden layout files in the list.
4. Merges all layout files from the list.

---

Custom module only extends the core layout file.

```
Namespace/Moduelname/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml
```

means you are extending product page into your module.

where as

```
app\design\frontend\<Vendor>\<theme>\Module_Vendor\layout\override\base\catalog_product_view.xml
```

here you are overriding the core layout.

then according to Magento layout processing if you are overriding layout in theme it will replace also extended layout (in custom module ).

Comment: How Magento 2 will handle the fallback logic for final rendering or merging the changes with Base

Comment: How the fallback will work if theme and module have base folders.

Comment: magento 2 theme do not contain base folder @Krishati95Dev

Comment: Please check the related question  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/160232/how-to-override-layout-file-which-is-already-override-by-other-theme-layout-o

Comment: As i mentioned in the question from official docs, we can use base folder for fallback, please refer Magento official "Core principals of theming in Magento 2"

Comment: as you ask `how the fallback work with base folder?` in documentation they have specify that `the new file that you place in the theme will be used instead of the parent theme layout file of base layout file.` @Krishati95Dev

Comment: @Krishati95Dev regarding that overriding question.if your theme is overriding from that base layout and if you want to override that theme/base file in your current theme means basically you are overriding base file.

Comment: Please provide the example with folder structure.

Comment: @Krishati95Dev there is one correction in your third point custom module can only extend the core layout file you can not override core layout in custom module.

Comment: @Krishati95Dev example added

Answer (score 2):

The base folder is an area to share for front-end representation logic (less, js, images, layout etc.), the resource which is for both admin and front-end, you can keep those files in the base folder.

For Example:

view/base/web/js/library.js which you are using in both for admin and front-end in this case you have should keep that library file on the base folder.

find the flowchart for fallback mechanism:

[image]

source [Click here][2]

Comment: then what is purpose of web folder ?

Comment: Files which you want to use in both adminhtml and front-end  those files should  be place on base folder.

Comment: How Magento 2 will handle the fallback logic for final rendering or merging the changes with BASE

Comment: How the fallback will work if theme and module have base folders.

Comment: Please check the related question  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/160232/how-to-override-layout-file-which-is-already-override-by-other-theme-layout-o